# How do I add speech output to Tensorflow's Object Detection API for the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm trying to add speech output to the Tensorflow Object Detection API on the raspberry pi. For example, if it detects a person from the picamera, I'm trying to get the program to say "person". When I use the code below for speech output, I get the error message "TypeError: expected str(string), bytes or os". This is likely because I'm assigning the wrong value to speech. The object detection itself is fine. Does anyone know what is the right variable/value for the object label or how I can add speech output another way? Thanks in advance. 
(I'm using Raspbian Buster and Model 4B)

SOLVED 
fixed code:

```
from subprocess import call 
object_number = int(classes[0][0]) 
object_label = category_index[object_number] 
speech = object_label[‘name’] 
call([“espeak”,speech])
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the question. You want to have your RPI speak the output of your Tensorflow Object Detection, is that correct? If yes, could you post the function that calls the speech API.

Comment: That is correct. However, what do you mean by the function that calls the speech API? The object detection API has no speech function. That's what I'm trying to add.

Comment: Could you show the entire implementation of that code then?

Comment: It's ok. I've solved the problem. Thank you though.